# What component is this? Royal 283

Tags: components

I have no idea what this is and found nothing on google

[image: Royal 283 3W 0Ohm22J]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the datasheet is here: http://www.royalohm.com/pdf/product2017/CementAxialPRW.pdf

Comment: I feel sorry for Q2. Poor thing's been decapitated o_O.

Comment: yes, mosfet will be replaced with better soldering :)

Comment: @TomCarpenter Maybe just punishment for it killing the resistor.

Comment: resistor is fine ! just checked

Comment: They really crowded that resistor though. I doubt it will actually take 3W in that spot.

Comment: What do you mean Trevor? I don't get it

Comment: Trevor is saying that resistor is packed in so tight to the components next to it that there's not going to be much air circulation to help cool the resistor.  It might not be able to dissipate 3W of heat when one side of it is basically covered up.

Comment: Yup.. what @JPhi1618 said.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is an "axial-lead cement wirewound resistor" rated at 3W. Resistance is 0.22\$\Omega\$ +/-5%. [Here](http://www.royalohm.com/pdf/product2017/CementAxialPRW.pdf) is a datasheet.

I've been in their factory. ;-)

Comment: LOL OK you win ;D

Comment: I put the datasheet in the comments 5 seconds after you...

Comment: @davidmneedham alas you get no rep for comments ;)

Comment: Well, Spehro, watching them being made is passive. Why, I've blown up a few, and replaced others in a repair;-)

Comment: @glen_geek Ever put enough energy into them to have them blow apart? I had a great demonstration of why we used expensive transformers rather than cheap resistors in our product.

Comment: Once in a while a question is just fun. Fun pictures, fun comments, and correct and complete answer.   +1  for question and answers !

Comment: You get an upvote, and YOU get an upvote!

Comment: +1 for the most accurate and detailed description of a simple and very common resistor.

Answer (score 9):

It is a 0.22 Ohm power resistor 3Watts

Answer (score 9):

It might be a 220 mΩ, 3 W power resistor.

Answer (score 9):

No its not it's a 3W 0.22 Ohm power resistor.

Comment: What is the "No its not" referring to?  Everyone seems to agree it's a 220 mOhm 3 W power resistor.

Comment: @OlinLathrop it was humor since I got in my answer 2s after you and Oldfart did I had to make mine look different ;)

Comment: Oh yes it is! (in honour of pantomime season)

Comment: @BrianDrummond "BEHIND YOU!!!!!!!!!" ;D